# How To Align buttons together

Tags: html, css

So I was adding columns and the buttons wouldn't line up well
is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Tried changing the div code inside but it still wouldn't do anything.

```css
.desc {
  color: rgb(232, 14, 14);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.game:hover {
  color: rgb(120, 9, 9);
  background-color: rgb(52, 3, 3);
}

.game {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.741);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(129, 5, 5);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.flex-container>div {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button {
  background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.center-screen {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 20px;
}

form {
  background-color: #4654e1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  all: unset;
  font: 16px system-ui;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search" class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="thumb" width="300" height="300" src="/Pages/games/wpnfire/wpnfire.jpg" alt="#" />
      <h1 style="color: white;">Text</h1>
      <p class="desc">Text</p>
      <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
      <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That is the CSS and HTML of the page and the columns

I don't know what to change in the code to get it to align up.

Comment: Share your code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way you can fix the problem :

```
    <div id="search" class="flex-container">
    <div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="thumb" width="300" height="300" src="/Pages/games/wpnfire/wpnfire.jpg" alt="#" />
            <h1 style="color: white;">Text</h1>
            <p class="desc">Text</p>
            <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
            <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="thumb" width="300" height="300" src="/Pages/games/wpnfire/wpnfire.jpg" alt="#" />
                <h1 style="color: white;">text</h1>
                <p class="desc">Text for testing the sort of the elements</p>
                <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
                <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

and the CSS will be like this :

```
            .desc {
            color: rgb(232, 14, 14);
            font-size: 16px;
            width:100%;
            /* padding: 5px; */
        }
        
        .game:hover {
            color: rgb(120, 9, 9);
            background-color: rgb(52, 3, 3);
        }
        
        .game {
            border: none;
            outline: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px 0;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.741);
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(129, 5, 5);
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 18px;
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            translate : 0px -10px;
        }
        
        .flex-container {
            width : 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: center;
        }
        
        .flex-container>div {
            display : flex;
            gap:20px;
            margin: 1px;
            padding: 3px;
            width : 100%
        }
        
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            max-width: 300px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            display:flex;
            align-items : center;
            justify-content : center;
            flex-direction:column;
            width : 100%;
            position:relative;
        }
        
        .thumb {
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        
        .button {
            background-color: orange;
            border: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
        
        .center-screen {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        
        form {
            background-color: #4654e1;
            width: 300px;
            height: 44px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        input {
            all: unset;
            font: 16px system-ui;
            color: #fff;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 6px 10px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the stuff above the buttons have different heights. You can fix this by putting those items in their own div and giving that div a height.

```
  <div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header-row">
        <img class="thumb" width="300" height="300" src="/Pages/games/wpnfire/wpnfire.jpg" alt="#" />
        <h1 style="color: white;">Text</h1>
        <p class="desc">Text</p>
        <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
      </div>
      <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.card-header-row: {
  height: '120px';
}
```

Comment: thanks but somehow it made it close together
@AustinPoulson

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I could think of was to have text cut off with ellipsis in the title and description if it's too long. I also made the size of the image elements to be consistent for each box so that everything would line up. I recommend refactoring the card class to use a flexbox, but this will also work. I also modified the HTML to use a random icon from the internet for demonstration purposes.

Here's a link to a JSFiddle with the modified code: https://jsfiddle.net/n7opzs9t/9/

Hope this helps!

```css
/* Added class for the title */
.title {
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 1em;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Added text wrapping and outer spacing for description*/
.desc {
  color: rgb(232, 14, 14);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-height: 2em;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/* Limited the width of the button to the size of the card and added spacing to the outside*/
.game {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.741);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(129, 5, 5);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
}

/* Moved stylings over to the css file for images*/
.thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="search" class="flex-container">
  <div class="card">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Windows_Settings_app_icon.png/1024px-Windows_Settings_app_icon.png" alt="#" />
      <h1 class="title">Text</h1>
      <p class="desc">Text</p>
      <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
      <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Windows_Settings_app_icon.png/1024px-Windows_Settings_app_icon.png" alt="#" />
      <h1 class="title">Text is way too long for this title</h1>
      <p class="desc">Text is way too long for this description</p>
      <div style="margin: 24px 0;"> <i class="fa-solid fa-keyboard"></i> </div>
      <a class="game" href="/Pages/games/wpnfire/">Press to play</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```